# c++ arrays vs pointers

Tags: c++

In C++ following is valid

```
    int *p = new int[3];
    *p=0;
    *(++p)=1;
```

Also following is valid

```
    int j[] = { 0, 1, 2};
    *j = 3;
```

Given, *j  =3 works, Why is following invalid

```
    *(++j)=4;//invalid.. lvalue required as increment operand
```

Comment: `j` is constant pointer to start array

Comment: @turbanoff: no, `j` is an array type, not a pointer type.

Comment: Note `*(j + 1)` is okay because you aren't trying to modify `j` itself.

Answer (score 3):

In an expression like this

```
*(++j)=4;//invalid.. lvalue required as increment operand
```

`j` which is an array int[3] "decays" to a pointer to the first element of that array. That pointer is an rvalue, and can't be assigned, therefore you can't do things like `*(++j)`.

In your other example `p` is a pointer which is non const and can be assigned:

```
 int *p = new int[3];
 *p=0;
 *(++p)=1;
```

The behavior you obtain with the rvalue is similar to what would happen with a const pointer:

```
 int const *p = new int[3];
 *p=0;
 *(++p)=1;
```

Comment: I think you are making the same mistake as the downvoted answer. `j` is an array, and you can't increment arrays.

Comment: `j` decays to a pointer but it's not constant as in `const`, it's just an _rvalue_. _rvalues_ of non-class type are never `const`.

Comment: Yes, your answer is much more accurate now.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays and pointers are similar, but this is one place where they are not.

If you want to iterate over an array, use a separate pointer variable:

```
int j[] = { 0, 1, 2};    
int* jp = j;
```

`jp` then points to the first element of `j`. Then:

```
*(++jp) = 4;
```

will work.